# Removing some particular rows in pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I want to delete some rows in pandas dataframe.

```
ID                Value

2012XY000         1
2012XY001         1
.                 
.
.
2015AB000         4
2015PQ001         5
.
.
.
2016DF00G         2
```

I want to delete rows whose ID does not start with 2015.
How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df.ID.str.startswith('2015'))
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
Name: ID, dtype: bool

print (df[df.ID.str.startswith('2015')])
          ID  Value
2  2015AB000      4
3  2015PQ001      5
```

EDIT by comment:

```
print (df)
          ID  Value
0  2012XY000      1
1  2012XY001      1
2  2015AB000      4
3  2015PQ001      5
4  2015XQ001      5
5  2016DF00G      2

print ((df.ID.str.startswith('2015')) & (df.ID.str[4] != 'X'))
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: ID, dtype: bool

print (df[(df.ID.str.startswith('2015')) & (df.ID.str[4] != 'X')])
          ID  Value
2  2015AB000      4
3  2015PQ001      5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works pretty much well. One more additional Query, if I wish to have all rows with 2015 starts, but not 2015X exclusive, how do I do that?

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot. Thanks for those fast replies :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.match` with regex string `r'^2015'`:

```
df[df.ID.str.match(r'^2015')]
```

[image]

To exclude those that have an `X` afterwards.

```
df[df.ID.str.match(r'^2015[^X]')]
```

The regex `r'^2015[^X]'` translates into

- `^2015` - must start with `2015`
- `[^X]` - character after `2015` must not be `X`

consider the `df`

[image]

then

```
df[df.ID.str.match(r'^2015[^X]')]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works pretty much well. One more additional Query, if I wish to have all rows with start 2015 , but not 2015X exclusively, how do I do that?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the explanation. Thanks a lot :D Thanks for fast reply too :)